# API for finding movie theatres

Tags: iphone

Is there any API that uses XML to get information about the nearest theatre and movies? I found some APIs but not with XML.

Comment: Try to be more specific.

Comment: In my app i want to get information about nearest theatres and movies.so is there any XMl links to implement this idea.

Comment: You must have this on your server, and from you server you can fetch different websites to get the data.

Comment: Thats ok.thank you.But if you know any xml links plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used, but http://www.tmsdatadirect.com/docs/movies/ seemed promising.